# How do I get linux to automatically run my python script in the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, linux

I've decided that it would be good for me to move outside of my .NET bubble and start experimenting with other technologies. I have Ubuntu12 running and python2.7 and 3.2 are installed. I can run code directly in the interpreters.

I have a basic script on the filesystem called Standalone.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

import sys

print("this is a standalone script.")
```

When I'm at my bash prompt I type `$ python3.2 Standalone.py`. I get a response saying `this is a standalone script`. But when I type `$ Standalone.py` then it tells me that the command is not found.

How do I run such scripts?

Thanks for any help.

### update

I changed the permissions of Standalone.py to 755. Then I ran the command:

```
$ ./Standalone.py
```

and received the message:

```
: No such file or directory
```

I then switched the permissions of Standalone.py back to 644. Then when I ran

```
$ ./Standalone.py
```

I received the message

```
-bash: ./Standalone.py: Permission denied
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Wow, that `: No such file or directory` part sounds weird... What happens when you run `/usr/bin/env python3.2` in bash?

Comment: @weronika - The interpreter runs when I enter /usr/bin/env python3.2

Comment: I figured it out. Somewhere alone the line my shebang became #!/usEr/bin/env python3.2 instead of #!/usr/bin/env python3.2 (I hang my head in shame) - Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @quakkels: So in future, *please* copy and paste scripts and error messages you have questions about to StackOverflow, instead of retyping the part you think is relevant.  If you would have copied your script, we would have noticed.  If you would have copied the full error message, which reads `/user/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, we would also have noticed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You need to make the script executable using

   ```sh
   chmod +x Standalone.py
   ```
2. Usually, the current directory is not searched for executable files, so you need to use

   ```sh
   ./Standalone.py
   ```

   to tell the shell that the script is in the current directory.

Comment: I didn't think about permissions needing to be set to executable. I ran the first step. But, on step2, I type `./Standalone.py` and I get the response of `No such file or directory`. When I run `ls` I see Standalone.py listed in green. I assume green means that it's executable now.

Comment: Just a side note if you plan on just double clicking the script you will need `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of every script every time or it will most likely not run.

Comment: As a side note, I'm running ubuntu 12 server, so there is no gui. Why do you think the `./Standalone.py` returns `No such file or directory` when it's in the same folder?

Comment: @heltonbiker: I am pretty sure you are wrong, for something to be executable it needs to be executable.

Comment: try typing `./Standa` and the hit [TAB] key a few times, are there any completions available?

Comment: @honk: did the test, and I was wrong, python scripts actually (of course) need the executable permissions to be run the `./file.py` way.

Comment: @F.C. - Yes... when I type `./Standa` hit tab, it autocompletes to './Standalone.py'. Then I hit enter and I get `No such file or directory`. argh!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your script file has linux newline (just `\n`) not windows newline (`\r\n`). Did you write the script on windows? This happened to me once. You should check your editor settings.

Comment: @quakkels Did you originally write the script on Windows?  Use vim and ":set list". Make sure you don't have a ^M on the end of that #! line.

Comment: Good tip. That wasn't the problem, but I didn't know about that vim command `:set list`

Comment: Awesome, this did it for me. had the same issue. I just set EOL conversion on NP++ to "UNIX" and re-uploaded my script to my vps. Works :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Your script should start with `#!/usr/bin/python` not `#!/usr/bin/env python3.2`
2. Make sure you're in the folder where your script is located you can check with `ls`
3. `chmod +x Standalone.py`
4. `./Standalone.py`

Comment: Thank you. I am in the same folder. Please see question update.

Comment: @quakkels when switching form 755 to 644 you have removed the permissions of execution for your script

Comment: yes. I know. when the execution permissions are present it can't find the file. I was demonstrating the commands were being run it the correct folder and the file was present.

Comment: I also checked with `ls` and the script file Standalone.py is in the current directory.

Comment: @quakkels what is the problem now?

Comment: with permissions on Standalone.py set to 755 and when i'm in the same folder as Standalone.py - when I run `./Standalone.py` I get the message: No such file or directory.

Comment: @quakkels: Are you aware that Linux file names are case-sensitive?  What does `ls ./Standalone.py` yield?

Comment: @SvenMarnach - `ls ./Standalone.py` prints `./Standalone.py`.

Comment: @quakkels you problem should be solved now take a look a the edit.

Comment: Can you please check if /usr/bin/python exists?

Comment: @weronika i have tried the the script with #!/usr/bin/env python3.2 i get the error '#!/usr/bin/env python3.2 : No such file or directory'but with #!/usr/bin/python every thing works fine

Comment: That probably just means you don't have python3.2 - in that case `#!/usr/bin/env python` will still do the same as `#!/usr/bin/python` in a more portable way.

Answer (score 0):

At first, to excecute a script it need to be executable. So you either have to do a chmod +x $file or a chmod 0740 $file. When you set the file permission to 644 you are putting the execute right away, so if gives you an error. If you are unsure of execution right and octal notation, you can use this : http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/0644/.
To really answer your question then, if you want to call the script with $file.py it needs to be in your PATH variable. You can display it with echo $PATH. Those are the directories that are searched for script to execute. So you simply need to give your script the executable right and put it in one of the directory given by your PATH.

Comment: even if I move the Standalone.py file to the `/usr/local/sbin` directory (which is listed in echo $PATH) I still get the `No such file or directory` error when I run `Standalone.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if /usr/bin/python or /usr/bin/python3.2 exists

Execute below comamnd:

```
which python3.2
```

and then use the resulting path on top of you script.